# Rendering three vertical dots using SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I have a pretty simple question but I can't seem to find a solution for it. I have the following SCSS code (can be found below) which works fine, but I think it could be simplified to get rid of the double code.

I'm trying to create 3 simple dots with CSS. I figured I could use one `div` and the `:before and :after` selectors. I'm looking for a pure (S)CSS solution and don't want to use icons/images. I have a working example but I feel like it could be a lot better structured.

Mainly I'm looking to change the selectors so I can get a format like:

```
div {
  // Styling for the div in it's normal state.
  [selector for div itself] &:after, &:before {
    // Styling for the div in it's normal state AND for it's :before and :after state
  }
  &:after, &:before {
    // Styling for JUST the :before and :after state
  }
  &:after {
    // Styling for JUST the :after state
  }
  &:before {
    // Styling for JUST the :before state
  }
}
```

Current code

SCSS:

```
.row-options-icon{
  padding: 2rem;
  &:hover{
    div, div:after, div:before{
      background-color: black;
    }
  }
  div {
    position: relative;
    border-radius:100px;
    background-color:gray;
    width:.5rem;
    height:.5rem;
    &:after, &:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      border-radius:100px;
      background-color:gray;
      width:.5rem;
      height:.5rem;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    &:after {
      top: -1rem;
    }
    &:before {
      top: 1rem;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row-options-icon">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

[Working Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPdmEB)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about [what your code does](//codereview.meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226) and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The current title states your concerns about the code; it needs an [edit] to simply *state the task*; see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @TobySpeight I edited it, hope it's more clear now

Comment: The title and explanation still focus on your concerns about the code rather than why you wrote it.  It's very hard to review code without properly understanding its purpose.

Comment: @TobySpeight I have edited it again, hoping to have implemented your feedback. If it still isn't correct than I am afraid I don't quite understand what you are trying to explain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is just `&`:

```
  div {
    position: relative;
    &, &:after, &:before {
      border-radius:100px;
      background-color:gray;
      width:.5rem;
      height:.5rem;
    }
    &:after, &:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    &:after {
      top: -1rem;
    }
    &:before {
      top: 1rem;
    }
  }
```